# Graphviz: optimize layout: Avoid blank space and edge crossings

Tags: graphviz

I have the following generated data:

```
graph test123 {"{}" -- "--plus"
"{}" -- "{.}"
"{}" -- "{/}"
"{}" -- "{//}"
"{}" -- "{/.}"
"{}" -- "{#}"
"{}" -- "{%}"
"{}" -- "{n}"
"{}" -- "{=perl expression=}"
"{n}" -- "{n.}"
"{n}" -- "{n/}"
"{n}" -- "{n//}"
"{n}" -- "{n/.}"
"{n.}" -- "{.}"
"{n/}" -- "{/}"
"{n//}" -- "{//}"
"{n/.}" -- "{/.}"
"{=perl expression=}" -- "--rpl"
"{=perl expression=}" -- "--parens"
"{=perl expression=}" -- "{=n perl expression=}"
"{=n perl expression=}" -- "{n}"
":::" -- "--arg-sep"
":::" -- "-a"
":::" -- "::::"
":::" -- ":::+"
":::" -- "::::+"
":::" -- "--link"
":::+" -- "::::+"
":::+" -- "--link"
"::::" -- "-a"
"::::" -- "::::+"
"::::" -- "--link"
"::::+" -- "-a"
"::::+" -- "--link"
"--null" -- "--delimiter"
"--arg-file" -- "--link"
"--arg-file" -- "{n}"
"--arg-file" -- "::::"
"--arg-file" -- "::::+"
"--arg-file" -- ":::"
"--arg-file-sep" -- "::::"
"--basefile" -- "--sshlogin"
"--basefile" -- "--transfer"
"--basefile" -- "--return"
"--basefile" -- "--cleanup"
"--basefile" -- "--workdir"
"--basenamereplace" -- "{/}"
"--basenameextensionreplace" -- "{/.}"
"--bin" -- "--group-by"
"--bin" -- "--round-robin"
"--bin" -- "--shard"
"--bg" -- "--fg"
"--bg" -- "man sem"
"--block" -- "-N"
"--block" -- "--pipe"
"--block" -- "--pipe-part"
"--block" -- "--round-robin"
"--blocktimeout" -- "--pipe"
"--cat" -- "--pipe"
"--cat" -- "--pipe-part"
"--cat" -- "--fifo"
"--cleanup" -- "--transfer"
"--cleanup" -- "--transferfile"
"--cleanup" -- "--sshlogin"
"--cleanup" -- "--return"
"--colsep" -- "--csv"
"--colsep" -- "{n}"
"--colsep" -- "--trim"
"--colsep" -- "--link"
"--compress" -- "--compress-program"
"--csv" -- "--pipe"
"--csv" -- "--link"
"--csv" -- "{n}"
"--ctag" -- "--tag"
"--ctagstring" -- "--ctag"
"--ctagstring" -- "--tagstring"
"--delay" -- "--retries"
"--delimiter" -- "--colsep"
"--dirnamereplace" -- "{//}"
"--dry-run" -- "-v"
"--env" -- "--record-env"
"--env" -- "--session"
"--env" -- "--sshlogin"
"--env" -- "command"
"--env" -- "env_parallel"
"--eta" -- "--bar"
"--eta" -- "--progress"
"--fg" -- "man sem"
"--fifo" -- "--pipe"
"--fifo" -- "--pipe-part"
"--filter-hosts" -- "--sshloginfile"
"--filter-hosts" -- "--sshlogin"
"--filter-hosts" -- "--retries"
"--group" -- "--line-buffer"
"--group" -- "--ungroup"
"--group-by" -- "--pipe"
"--group-by" -- "--pipe-part"
"--group-by" -- "--shard"
"--group-by" -- "--round-robin"
"--header" -- "--colsep"
"--header" -- "--pipe"
"--header" -- "--pipe-part"
"--hostgroups" -- "--sshlogin"
"--hostgroups" -- "$PARALLEL_HOSTGROUPS"
"--hostgroups" -- "$PARALLEL_ARGHOSTGROUPS"
"--joblog" -- "--resume"
"--joblog" -- "--resume-failed"
"--jobs" -- "--use-cores-instead-of-threads"
"--jobs" -- "--use-sockets-instead-of-threads"
"--keep-order" -- "--group"
"--keep-order" -- "--line-buffer"
"-L" -- "-N"
"-L" -- "-l"
"-L" -- "--block"
"-L" -- "-X"
"-L" -- "-m"
"-L" -- "--xargs"
"-L" -- "--pipe"
"--limit" -- "--memfree"
"--limit" -- "--load"
"--line-buffer" -- "--ungroup"
"--xapply" -- "--header"
"--xapply" -- ":::+"
"--xapply" -- "::::+"
"--load" -- "--jobs"
"--controlmaster" -- "--ssh"
"--controlmaster" -- "--sshlogin"
"-m" -- "-X"
"-m" -- "--xargs"
"--memfree" -- "--termseq"
"--memfree" -- "--retries"
"--memfree" -- "--memsuspend"
"--max-replace-args" -- "--pipe"
"--max-replace-args" -- "--block"
"--max-replace-args" -- "-m"
"--max-replace-args" -- "-X"
"--nonall" -- "--onall"
"--nonall" -- "--sshlogin"
"--onall" -- "--sshlogin"
"--output-as-files" -- "--results"
"--pipe" -- "--recstart"
"--pipe" -- "--recend"
"--pipe" -- "--pipe-part"
"--pipe" -- "-N"
"--plus" -- "--rpl"
"--progress" -- "--bar"
"--parens" -- "--rpl"
"--noswap" -- "--memfree"
"--noswap" -- "--memsuspend"
"--record-env" -- "--session"
"--recstart" -- "--regexp"
"--recstart" -- "--remove-rec-sep"
"--results" -- "--files"
"--results" -- "--tag"
"--results" -- "--header"
"--results" -- "--joblog"
"--resume" -- "--results"
"--resume" -- "--resume-failed"
"--resume" -- "--retries"
"--resume-failed" -- "--retry-failed"
"--resume-failed" -- "--retries"
"--retry-failed" -- "--joblog"
"--retry-failed" -- "--resume"
"--retry-failed" -- "--retries"
"--retries" -- "--termseq"
"--retries" -- "--sshlogin"
"--return" -- "--transfer"
"--return" -- "--transferfile"
"--return" -- "--sshlogin"
"--return" -- "--workdir"
"--round-robin" -- "--shard"
"--max-chars" -- "-X"
"--max-chars" -- "-m"
"--max-chars" -- "--xargs"
"--max-chars" -- "--max-line-length-allowed"
"--max-chars" -- "--show-limits"
"--show-limits" -- "--max-line-length-allowed"
"--semaphore" -- "man sem"
"--semaphore" -- "--bg"
"--semaphore" -- "--fg"
"--semaphore" -- "--semaphorename"
"--semaphore" -- "--semaphoretimeout"
"--semaphore" -- "--wait"
"--semaphorename" -- "man sem"
"--semaphoretimeout" -- "man sem"
"--ssh" -- "--sshlogin"
"--sshlogin" -- "--transferfile"
"--sshlogin" -- "--trc"
"--sshlogin" -- "--sshloginfile"
"--sshlogin" -- "--workdir"
"--tag" -- "--tagstring"
"--tmpdir" -- "--compress"
"--timeout" -- "--termseq"
"--verbose" -- "-v"
"--verbose" -- "-p"
"--transferfile" -- "--workdir"
"--transferfile" -- "--basefile"
"--trc" -- "--transfer"
"--trc" -- "--return"
"--trc" -- "--cleanup"
"--extensionreplace" -- "{.}"
"-v" -- "-t"
"--wait" -- "man sem"
"--xargs" -- "-X"
}
```

It generates a graph that is technically correct, but [not very visually pleasing](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=graph%20test123%20%7B%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22--plus%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B.%7D%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F%7D%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F%2F%7D%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F.%7D%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%23%7D%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%25%7D%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%7D%22%0A%22%7B%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%3Dperl%20expression%3D%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn%7D%22%20--%20%22%7Bn.%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn%7D%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%2F%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn%7D%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%2F%2F%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn%7D%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%2F.%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn.%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B.%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn%2F%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn%2F%2F%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F%2F%7D%22%0A%22%7Bn%2F.%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F.%7D%22%0A%22%7B%3Dperl%20expression%3D%7D%22%20--%20%22--rpl%22%0A%22%7B%3Dperl%20expression%3D%7D%22%20--%20%22--parens%22%0A%22%7B%3Dperl%20expression%3D%7D%22%20--%20%22%7B%3Dn%20perl%20expression%3D%7D%22%0A%22%7B%3Dn%20perl%20expression%3D%7D%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%7D%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22--arg-sep%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22-a%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22--link%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%20--%20%22--link%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22-a%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%22%20--%20%22--link%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%20--%20%22-a%22%0A%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%20--%20%22--link%22%0A%22--null%22%20--%20%22--delimiter%22%0A%22--arg-file%22%20--%20%22--link%22%0A%22--arg-file%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%7D%22%0A%22--arg-file%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%22%0A%22--arg-file%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%0A%22--arg-file%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%22%0A%22--arg-file-sep%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%22%0A%22--basefile%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--basefile%22%20--%20%22--transfer%22%0A%22--basefile%22%20--%20%22--return%22%0A%22--basefile%22%20--%20%22--cleanup%22%0A%22--basefile%22%20--%20%22--workdir%22%0A%22--basenamereplace%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F%7D%22%0A%22--basenameextensionreplace%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F.%7D%22%0A%22--bin%22%20--%20%22--group-by%22%0A%22--bin%22%20--%20%22--round-robin%22%0A%22--bin%22%20--%20%22--shard%22%0A%22--bg%22%20--%20%22--fg%22%0A%22--bg%22%20--%20%22man%20sem%22%0A%22--block%22%20--%20%22-N%22%0A%22--block%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--block%22%20--%20%22--pipe-part%22%0A%22--block%22%20--%20%22--round-robin%22%0A%22--blocktimeout%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--cat%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--cat%22%20--%20%22--pipe-part%22%0A%22--cat%22%20--%20%22--fifo%22%0A%22--cleanup%22%20--%20%22--transfer%22%0A%22--cleanup%22%20--%20%22--transferfile%22%0A%22--cleanup%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--cleanup%22%20--%20%22--return%22%0A%22--colsep%22%20--%20%22--csv%22%0A%22--colsep%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%7D%22%0A%22--colsep%22%20--%20%22--trim%22%0A%22--colsep%22%20--%20%22--link%22%0A%22--compress%22%20--%20%22--compress-program%22%0A%22--csv%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--csv%22%20--%20%22--link%22%0A%22--csv%22%20--%20%22%7Bn%7D%22%0A%22--ctag%22%20--%20%22--tag%22%0A%22--ctagstring%22%20--%20%22--ctag%22%0A%22--ctagstring%22%20--%20%22--tagstring%22%0A%22--delay%22%20--%20%22--retries%22%0A%22--delimiter%22%20--%20%22--colsep%22%0A%22--dirnamereplace%22%20--%20%22%7B%2F%2F%7D%22%0A%22--dry-run%22%20--%20%22-v%22%0A%22--env%22%20--%20%22--record-env%22%0A%22--env%22%20--%20%22--session%22%0A%22--env%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--env%22%20--%20%22command%22%0A%22--env%22%20--%20%22env_parallel%22%0A%22--eta%22%20--%20%22--bar%22%0A%22--eta%22%20--%20%22--progress%22%0A%22--fg%22%20--%20%22man%20sem%22%0A%22--fifo%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--fifo%22%20--%20%22--pipe-part%22%0A%22--filter-hosts%22%20--%20%22--sshloginfile%22%0A%22--filter-hosts%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--filter-hosts%22%20--%20%22--retries%22%0A%22--group%22%20--%20%22--line-buffer%22%0A%22--group%22%20--%20%22--ungroup%22%0A%22--group-by%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--group-by%22%20--%20%22--pipe-part%22%0A%22--group-by%22%20--%20%22--shard%22%0A%22--group-by%22%20--%20%22--round-robin%22%0A%22--header%22%20--%20%22--colsep%22%0A%22--header%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--header%22%20--%20%22--pipe-part%22%0A%22--hostgroups%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--hostgroups%22%20--%20%22%24PARALLEL_HOSTGROUPS%22%0A%22--hostgroups%22%20--%20%22%24PARALLEL_ARGHOSTGROUPS%22%0A%22--joblog%22%20--%20%22--resume%22%0A%22--joblog%22%20--%20%22--resume-failed%22%0A%22--jobs%22%20--%20%22--use-cores-instead-of-threads%22%0A%22--jobs%22%20--%20%22--use-sockets-instead-of-threads%22%0A%22--keep-order%22%20--%20%22--group%22%0A%22--keep-order%22%20--%20%22--line-buffer%22%0A%22-L%22%20--%20%22-N%22%0A%22-L%22%20--%20%22-l%22%0A%22-L%22%20--%20%22--block%22%0A%22-L%22%20--%20%22-X%22%0A%22-L%22%20--%20%22-m%22%0A%22-L%22%20--%20%22--xargs%22%0A%22-L%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--limit%22%20--%20%22--memfree%22%0A%22--limit%22%20--%20%22--load%22%0A%22--line-buffer%22%20--%20%22--ungroup%22%0A%22--xapply%22%20--%20%22--header%22%0A%22--xapply%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%0A%22--xapply%22%20--%20%22%3A%3A%3A%3A%2B%22%0A%22--load%22%20--%20%22--jobs%22%0A%22--controlmaster%22%20--%20%22--ssh%22%0A%22--controlmaster%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22-m%22%20--%20%22-X%22%0A%22-m%22%20--%20%22--xargs%22%0A%22--memfree%22%20--%20%22--termseq%22%0A%22--memfree%22%20--%20%22--retries%22%0A%22--memfree%22%20--%20%22--memsuspend%22%0A%22--max-replace-args%22%20--%20%22--pipe%22%0A%22--max-replace-args%22%20--%20%22--block%22%0A%22--max-replace-args%22%20--%20%22-m%22%0A%22--max-replace-args%22%20--%20%22-X%22%0A%22--nonall%22%20--%20%22--onall%22%0A%22--nonall%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--onall%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--output-as-files%22%20--%20%22--results%22%0A%22--pipe%22%20--%20%22--recstart%22%0A%22--pipe%22%20--%20%22--recend%22%0A%22--pipe%22%20--%20%22--pipe-part%22%0A%22--pipe%22%20--%20%22-N%22%0A%22--plus%22%20--%20%22--rpl%22%0A%22--progress%22%20--%20%22--bar%22%0A%22--parens%22%20--%20%22--rpl%22%0A%22--noswap%22%20--%20%22--memfree%22%0A%22--noswap%22%20--%20%22--memsuspend%22%0A%22--record-env%22%20--%20%22--session%22%0A%22--recstart%22%20--%20%22--regexp%22%0A%22--recstart%22%20--%20%22--remove-rec-sep%22%0A%22--results%22%20--%20%22--files%22%0A%22--results%22%20--%20%22--tag%22%0A%22--results%22%20--%20%22--header%22%0A%22--results%22%20--%20%22--joblog%22%0A%22--resume%22%20--%20%22--results%22%0A%22--resume%22%20--%20%22--resume-failed%22%0A%22--resume%22%20--%20%22--retries%22%0A%22--resume-failed%22%20--%20%22--retry-failed%22%0A%22--resume-failed%22%20--%20%22--retries%22%0A%22--retry-failed%22%20--%20%22--joblog%22%0A%22--retry-failed%22%20--%20%22--resume%22%0A%22--retry-failed%22%20--%20%22--retries%22%0A%22--retries%22%20--%20%22--termseq%22%0A%22--retries%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--return%22%20--%20%22--transfer%22%0A%22--return%22%20--%20%22--transferfile%22%0A%22--return%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--return%22%20--%20%22--workdir%22%0A%22--round-robin%22%20--%20%22--shard%22%0A%22--max-chars%22%20--%20%22-X%22%0A%22--max-chars%22%20--%20%22-m%22%0A%22--max-chars%22%20--%20%22--xargs%22%0A%22--max-chars%22%20--%20%22--max-line-length-allowed%22%0A%22--max-chars%22%20--%20%22--show-limits%22%0A%22--show-limits%22%20--%20%22--max-line-length-allowed%22%0A%22--semaphore%22%20--%20%22man%20sem%22%0A%22--semaphore%22%20--%20%22--bg%22%0A%22--semaphore%22%20--%20%22--fg%22%0A%22--semaphore%22%20--%20%22--semaphorename%22%0A%22--semaphore%22%20--%20%22--semaphoretimeout%22%0A%22--semaphore%22%20--%20%22--wait%22%0A%22--semaphorename%22%20--%20%22man%20sem%22%0A%22--semaphoretimeout%22%20--%20%22man%20sem%22%0A%22--ssh%22%20--%20%22--sshlogin%22%0A%22--sshlogin%22%20--%20%22--transferfile%22%0A%22--sshlogin%22%20--%20%22--trc%22%0A%22--sshlogin%22%20--%20%22--sshloginfile%22%0A%22--sshlogin%22%20--%20%22--workdir%22%0A%22--tag%22%20--%20%22--tagstring%22%0A%22--tmpdir%22%20--%20%22--compress%22%0A%22--timeout%22%20--%20%22--termseq%22%0A%22--verbose%22%20--%20%22-v%22%0A%22--verbose%22%20--%20%22-p%22%0A%22--transferfile%22%20--%20%22--workdir%22%0A%22--transferfile%22%20--%20%22--basefile%22%0A%22--trc%22%20--%20%22--transfer%22%0A%22--trc%22%20--%20%22--return%22%0A%22--trc%22%20--%20%22--cleanup%22%0A%22--extensionreplace%22%20--%20%22%7B.%7D%22%0A%22-v%22%20--%20%22-t%22%0A%22--wait%22%20--%20%22man%20sem%22%0A%22--xargs%22%20--%20%22-X%22%0A%20%20%20%20n128%0A%7D).

I have tried using `dot`, `neato`, `fdp`, and `sfdp`, and each of them fail in some of these ways:

- node circles overlays: This can cause the text to be unreadable.
- edges cross node circles: Edges should never touch a node circle.
- waste of paper: There is way too much blank paper.
- edge crossings: Many of the solutions have edges crossing needlessly, crossings that could be avoided by simply moving a node or adjusting the line's path.

The least crappy solution is from `dot`: It reaches the first 2 goals perfectly, and it seems goals 3+4 could be improved a lot if I could disable it's hierarchical mode and let it place the nodes more freely.

`neato` does a better job of not wasting paper, but a crap job of first two goals.

[This example](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/tools/Graphviz/examples/edge-crossing) manually uncrosses edges. But since my graph is generated, I want something like this to happen automatically.

How can I tell the layout engines to optimize for the 4 goals - possibly by assigning a cost to each of the 4 goals?

Answer (score 0):

Using `neato` and adding this:

```
       graph test123 {
overlap=false;
splines=true;
sep=.1;
```

helps a lot: Goal 1+2 is completed. There are still many unneeded edge crossings that could trivially be solved (e.g. swap two nodes, let an edge go left of a node instead of right), but there are fewer.

Comment: You might experiment with mode and model attributes for neato -  for E in neato ; do for Ml in  circuit subset mds;do for M in hier major KK sgd ipsep ;do f=ole1.gv; T=svg; F=`basename $f .gv`;$E -Gmodel=$Ml -Gmode=$M -T$T $f >$F.$E.$M.$Ml.$T;firefox $F.$E.$M.$Ml.$T &done ; done; done